# Word for someone who's slowly turning out-of-date, especially in thinking or ideas

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

There's a verb *забронзоветь* in Russian formed from word "bronze" with the following meanings when applied to a person:

1. to get a shade of bronze (like become a hero to become worthy of a bronze monument)
2. to stop self-educating, progressing intellectually
3. to become an idol, with shade of **losing the actuality, freshness**, **start moving into past**

Maybe English has sort of common and accepted word for this?

Note: I am looking for a term to be applied to a great, known person, like politician, philosopher or other researcher, added to all the meaning.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence or two.

Comment: Maybe ***ossifying***?

Comment: @DanBron from its definitions it looks amazingly close!

Comment: @Croll Use it in good health. And of course if it’s not quite what you’re looking for, you can use it as an entry point for a thesaurus scan.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, the adjective **superannuated**, means "1 : outmoded, old-fashioned 2 a : incapacitated or disqualified for active duty by advanced age," and the verb **superannuate** means "1 : to make declare or prove obsolete or out-of-date 2 : to retire and pension because of age or infirmity." It would seem to follow that the process of moving toward obsolescence might be termed **superannuating**.

Answer (score 2):

**Stagnating** has a similar meaning but less positive connotations than you've described. It is less a sense of change being unnecessary as legendary status has been attained and more of an unwillingness to change due to a lack of outside influence.

**Calcifying** could also be used, and retains the sense of a change in material composition from the original. Whilst not commonly used outside a literal context, I have heard it used in reference to people who as they age becoming set in their world views.

Comment: In stagnating i see portion of additional meaning that i cannot express, but the second looks just like the real alternative and besides that this is really interesting new word, thanks.

Comment: Applied to a once great person - I do not get that sense in this answer.

Comment: @lbf fair point- whilst both of these terms _could_ be used in that context, they are by no means exclusive to that application.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any single word, but the thought could be expressed in several ways:

- He is past his best.
- He is past his sell-by date.
- He is resting on his laurels.
- He is coasting.

I rather wish we did have such a word.

Comment: single word request.  This answer should be in comments.